# Is there a benefit of not killing enemies as Evan?

Tags: hotline-miami-2

Is there a difference if I choose to kill enemies as opposed to knocking them out? In the first mission as Evan I tried not killing them, but it seems the game wants you to do things peacefully, a la Batman.

Is there a change in the ending or what I get as rewards if I go  nonlethal as Evan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two benefits for not killing enemies:

- There is 1 achievement for playing all of Evan's scenes without killing anyone
- You can disarm guns to extend your combo meter
- You get more points for knocking enemies unconcious as opposed to killing them